# CORS Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I am using .Net Core 3. I have programmed an API being called by a SPA hosted in a .Net Core Web Project.
For one POST action in the API, I get a CORS error in Chrome as well as Firefox while for another POST action in the same controller of the API, everything works fine.

The error that I get is

```
Access to fetch at 'https://subdomain1.domain1.com:50003/api/v1/projects/project' from origin 
'https://subdomain2.domain2.com:50002' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 
'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

In the API,
In the startup class, I have following

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "AllowOrigin";
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     CorsPolicyBuilder builder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
     CorsPolicy policy = builder.WithOrigins("https://subdomain2.domain2.com:50002")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .Build();
     services.AddCors(options =>
     {
          options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, policy);
     });

     services.AddControllers();

     services
     .AddAuthentication("Bearer")
     .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions => {
          jwtOptions.Authority = "https://subdomain.domain.com:50001";
          jwtOptions.Audience = "portal-api";
          jwtOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
     });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
          app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }

     var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
     provider.Mappings[".hrc"] = "application/octet-stream";
     provider.Mappings[".obj"] = "application/octet-stream";

     app.UseHttpsRedirection();

     app.UseRouting();

     app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseAuthorization();

     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
          endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
     });
     app.UseMvc();
}
```

In the API controller, I have a POST action for which  I don't get any CORS error

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[action]")]
[ActionName("thumbnail")]
public async Task<IActionResult> thumbnail([FromBody]dataDTO model)
{
     .
     .
     .
}
```

In the same API, I have another POST action, for which the browser gives the above mentioned CORS error

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("project")]
[ActionName("project")]
public async Task<IActionResult> projectAdd([FromBody]projectDTO project)
{
     .
     .
     .
}
```

I have already tried moving the `app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);` to the top of `configure` function in `startup.cs`. It did not help.

I have also tried moving the `app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);` statement and changing its order in `configure` with no difference.

In firefox, I have also verified that there is a `Origin` header in the request to the action for which we are getting CORS error.

Comment: Is this being hosted in IIS? I've seen IIS block the HTTP OPTIONS verb from and then give this error as a result. Check the Request Filtering in IIS.

Comment: @Muhammad Tauseef, Could you please paste the url of the API for which you are not getting CORS error?

Comment: @mason if it were IIS, wouldn't it fail for the other request as well.

Comment: @viswanathaSwamy I am sorry I cannot share the actual URL. But the dummy URLs that I used in the code snippets above gives an idea about the kind of hosting configuration I have.

Comment: @MuhammadTauseef atleast could you please paste is from port onwards. Ex: 50003/api/v1/projects/project, 50003/api/v1/projects/thumbnail. Something like this.

Comment: @MuhammadTauseef You're right, didn't see that part of your question.

Comment: @MuhammadTauseef the other difference I am seeing is 1. The method which is not troubling is marked with [Route("[action]")], and 2. The method which is **troubling** is marked [Route("**Project**")]

Comment: @ViswanathaSwamy I have tried changing that. I made one `Route("thumbnail")` and the other `Route["project"]`. Still `Thumbnail` is working `Project` is not.